# handbrake trusty

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, handbrake

I'm trying to install the current version of handbrake on Trusty. I installed from the default repos and found it only supported the `MKV` format.

After Googling, I found everyone installs from the `stebbins/handbrake-releases` ppa. According to the instructions on the launchpad site I added the following lines to my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu trusty main
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

produces the following output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  handbrake-gtk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package handbrake-gtk.
(Reading database ... 286316 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../handbrake-gtk_7313svnppa1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking handbrake-gtk (7313svnppa1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up handbrake-gtk (7313svnppa1~trusty1) ...
```

But there is no handbrake:

```
brian@estuary:~$ which handbrake
brian@estuary:~$ which handbrake-gtk
```

How do I install handbrake on Trusty (lubuntu-desktop)? I had this working perfectly on Precise. I must be missing something stupid and obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-snapshots)

The GTK version is in the `handbrake-gtk` and has the path

```
/usr/bin/ghb
```

---

The CLI version is in the package `handbrake-cli`

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-cli
```

with the path

```
/usr/bin/HandBrakeCLI
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. I guess that's how they resolved the name conflict. Didn't know that before.